# ASIFormDataRequest request string

Tags: ios, http, post, asihttprequest

I am using ASIFormDataRequest for send request on server. My question is - how can I check request string that should be send to server.

For example string like this:

```
client=100001&time=1341271289&sign=99f031b0189aa006ee19ac22e77032a
d&city=2&name=%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F&phone=050+111+22+33&email=user
%40mafia.ua&text=%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D1%8B+
%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE
```

I mean I need to out this string for example to NSLog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locate your ASIHTTPRequestConfig.h file and look for line

```
 // When set to 1, ASIFormDataRequests will print information about the request body to the console 
    #ifndef DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST
    #define DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST 0
    #endif
```

Set `DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST 1` and you`re done!